# Set Tags dynamically in Gitlab CI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci

in our project setup we have different environments that run in different AWS accounts. The AWS accounts have no common link (like a parent account) and should remain separated.

In our Gitlab CI script we have a logic that evaluates the target environment (based on the branch the commit happened in).
The idea is now to dynamically set a tag for the tasks that links there execution to the Gitlab Runner in the "right" AWS account.
How can that be achieved?

Of course we could also duplicate all the tasks - one copy for each environment/tag - and add a condition to that. But that seems to create some overhead...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered whether you really need the job to run on a runner in a particular account? The runner can always have credentials that are permitted for any account. Otherwise, duplicating the jobs (can be made easier with anchors/extends) with `rules:` or `only: [branch_name]` is probably what you want to do until [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742) is resolved.